# How to use MDCTabBar

Tags: ios, swift, material-components

i made an app with MDCTabBar and it look perfect but i don't know how to setup childView with it 
what i already done is :

```
let Tab = MDCTabBar()
Tab.items = [some items]
Tab.itemAppearance = .titles
    Tab.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]

Tab.sizeToFit()
Tab.tintColor = UIColor.green
Tab.barTintColor = UIColor.black
Tab.selectedItem = Tab.items.first
Tab.selectedItem = Tab.items.first
appBar.headerStackView.bottomBar = Tab
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/170353/introduction-google-material-design-ios

Search for adding a tabbar.

Comment: @Mukul-More thanks but as i said i've added the TabBar i just don't know how to control child view with it

Answer (score 5):

`MDCTabBar` itself is just a view—you can set a delegate to be notified of changes to the selected tab, but you would then have to swap view controllers yourself.

Instead, try a [`MDCTabBarController`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/blob/develop/components/Tabs/src/MDCTabBarViewController.h), which manages view controllers for you and switches between them as the user selects different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for `MCDTabBar`

Firstly you create a delegate in an extension.

```
//MARK: - Tab Bar Delegate
extension ViewController: MDCTabBarDelegate {
    func tabBar(_ tabBar: MDCTabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        guard let index = tabBar.items.firstIndex(of: item) else { return }
        viewModel.selectedTabbarIndex = index
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Then we create another extension with functions that will setup Tab Bar:

```
//MARK: - Functions
extension ViewController {
    
    func configureTabbar() {
        tabbarView.clipsToBounds = false
        tabbarView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        tabBar = MDCTabBar(frame: .zero)
        tabBar.itemAppearance = .titles
        tabBar.tintColor = .brightSkyBlue
        tabBar.setTitleColor(.neutralDark, for: .selected)
        tabBar.setTitleColor(.grey2, for: .normal)
        tabBar.selectedItemTitleFont = Font.semibold.size(13)
        tabBar.unselectedItemTitleFont = Font.semibold.size(13)
        tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        tabBar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        tabBar.clipsToBounds = false
        tabBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        tabBar.delegate = self
        tabBar.sizeToFit()
        
        self.tabbarView.addSubview(self.tabBar)
        
    }
    
    func configureTabBarCategories() {
        for (index, categorie) in viewModel.categories.enumerated() {
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: categorie, image: nil, tag: index)
            self.tabBar.items.append(tabBarItem)
        }
    }
}
```

And in `viewDidLoad` you just call the functions. (Also, please check the whole ViewController class I shared below.)

```
import UIKit
import MaterialComponents.MaterialTabs

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tabbarView: UIView!
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    var viewModel: ViewModel!
    var tabBar: MDCTabBar!

    //MARK: - View Did Load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureTabbar()
        configureTabBarCategories()
    }

    //MARK: - View Will Load
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }
    
    //MARK: - View Will Layout Subviews
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
        tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tabbarView.frame.width, height: self.tabbarView.frame.height)
    }
    
    
}
```

The purpose of many extensions is to keep the code clear and well organized.

Then you should have something like this in your ViewModel:

```
class SubscriptionsViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    
    var categories: [String] = [
        "First",
        "Second",
        "Third",
        "Fourth"
    ]

    //Sections
    let FirstFilterIndex = 0
    let SecondFilterIndex = 1
    let ThirdFilterIndex = 2
    let FourthFilterIndex = 3

    func getSubscriptions() -> [Subscription] {
         switch selectedTabbarIndex {
         case FirstFilterIndex:
            return someData1 //You decide what data to show.
         case SecondFilterIndex:
            return someData2 //You decide what data to show.
         case ThirdFilterIndex:
            return someData3 //You decide what data to show.
         case FourthFilterIndex:
            return someData4 //You decide what data to show.
        default:
            return []
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create view like below code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
 var tabBar = MDCTabBar()

  viewType = self.viewTypeDict[0]

    tabBar = MDCTabBar(frame: container.bounds)

    tabBar.items = [ UITabBarItem(title: "Type1", image: nil, tag: 0),
                     UITabBarItem(title: "Type2", image: nil, tag: 1),
                     UITabBarItem(title: "Type3", image: nil, tag: 2),
                     UITabBarItem(title: "Type4", image: nil, tag: 3)
    ]
    tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items[0]
    tabBar.delegate = self

    tabBar.itemAppearance = .titles
    tabBar.alignment = .justified
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    tabBar.barTintColor = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
    tabBar.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleBottomMargin]
    tabBar.sizeToFit()
    tabBar.bottomDividerColor = UIColor.white
    container.addSubview(tabBar)
```

Comment: This not solve the problem: he wants to manage child views, not to show tabbar